# Import third-party libraries into JHipster 6 application

Tags: angular, jhipster

I am currently migrating my old project based on JHipster into new version - JHipster 6, where  is used Angular 8.
I have problem with `angular.json` file. After generating new project, this file looks like that:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "panel": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src/main/webapp",
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "skipTests": true,
          "style": "scss"
        },
        "@schematics/angular:directive": {
          "skipTests": true
        },
        "@schematics/angular:guard": {
          "skipTests": true
        },
        "@schematics/angular:pipe": {
          "skipTests": true
        },
        "@schematics/angular:service": {
          "skipTests": true
        }
      },
      "prefix": "jhi",
      "architect": {}
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "panel",
  "cli": {
    "packageManager": "npm"
  }
}
```

There is no place to add new scripts or styles, so I added content of `architect`.

```
      "architect": {
    "build": {
      "options": {
        "outputPath": "target/www/app",
        "scripts": [
          "node_modules/@fullcalendar/core/main.min.js"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
```

I was trying three different ways of path ( `"node_modules"`, `"../note_modules"` and `"./node_modules"`). Without success. Script was not imported into application. I think that is conected with JHipster structure.

Any ideas how to add external JS scripts like fullcalendar or jquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer, which was really easy. There is file `vendor.ts`, which is located in `src/main/webapp/app` directory. 
To add external scripts to JHipster 6 it is enough to import it like this:

```
import '@fullcalendar/core/main.min';
```

Styles can be imported in similar way (`vendor.scss`).

```
@import '~@fullcalendar/core/main.min.css';
```

Comment: This is also documented in your project's README.md